# Assigning a decimal value to object causing loss in precision

Tags: vb.net, casting

I have a value 123456789012345.89, which i am assigning to object type variable. By default, it is assigned as double object and lost precision (123456789012346) as value is too big for a double type. Is there any way i can get that value in object as decimal instead of double?

```
Dim obj As Object = 123456789012345.89
Dim deci As Decimal = obj
Console.WriteLine(deci)
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString())
```

Comment: Do you have to use an `Object`?

Comment: Yes it is by design, cant change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the correct type by using `123456789012345.89D` instead of `123456789012345.89`:

```
Dim obj As Object = 123456789012345.89D ' now it's a Decimal
Dim deci As Decimal = DirectCast(obj, Decimal)
Console.WriteLine(deci)
```

I also strongly recommend to set `Option Strict` to `On`. Then you have to use `DirectCast`(or `CType`) to cast the object to decimal. But you gain compile time safety.

[MSDN: Constant and Literal Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dzy06xhf.aspx)